# Visual Studio C# Question

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Say I have a program where a user is presented with a treeview of multiple directories and must check desired file/directories that they would like to later be copied.

That aside once the user has selected the files how can I go about creating a separate executable after a button is clicked that will perform the copy of the selected paths that were chosen in the main/first application?

I hope I've clearly expressed the goal I am trying to achieve, I did not feel this would required me to release my projects current code due to the simplicity of the task.

Comment: Have a look at [TLP,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Not sure how that is relevant.

Comment: @OliverJacot-Descombes I need a simpler answer im sure from my question you can assume im very inexperienced and any Microsoft page that explains the concept in the most confusing way possible will be little help to me

Comment: You want the program to make another program which you later run and it does the copy you specified? Maybe it could output a .bat file or powershell script?

Comment: What you probably need, is not to create and start another executable but multitasking, i.e. the ability to start another thread copying your files that runs in background. You can do that with [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) as well.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes im familiar with multi-threading and the background workers but in my case i would like the File.Copy to be called within another executable.........But the initial program would contain a list array and corresponding destinations, as this would be set by the user.............What im asking is how can i go about creating this secondary program to perform this task separately, i need it to be in another executable for later dispribution.......... the first program is only to obtain the user inputted files and their corresponding destinations

Comment: Do you really need to generate an executable? An alternative could be to generate a bat script which performs the copying. This would be much simpler. Or generate a configuration file which could then be read by the executable.

Comment: So are you basically asking how to implement `copy.exe`, an executable built in to Windows? Is there any particular reason why you can't simply use `copy.exe`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the [CodeDom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Maybe something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() {{ “CompilerVersion”, “v4.0” }});
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { “mscorlib.dll”, “System.Core.dll” }, “NewProgram.exe”, true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @”using System.IO;
            class Program {
              public static void Main(string[] args) {
                  File.Copy(""c:\temp\from.txt"",""c:\temp\to.txt"");
              }
            }”);
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this answer fits my needs best so far......... could this be modified to grab a list array of paths and corresponding destinations that would be created in the initial application before calling on to this CodeDom..........Thanks for your help

Comment: Why the downvotes, folks?

Comment: could you help with what i said in my previous comment?

Comment: @JohnWu probably because it is answering an off-topic question. Once the question is closed, it and its answers need negative scores for Roomba to handle the question (it is a bit more complicated but that is the short version).